# Unable to get property 'ClientVariables' of undefined or null reference in CRM 2013

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, crm, dynamics-crm-4, dynamics-crm-2013

I have a task to upgrade the CRM 4.0 to CRM 2013 and CRM have too much customization. i have change the code and then upgrade to CRM 2011 then apply RU 16 on CRM 2011 then get the data base and import in the CRM 2013.
Now in CRM 2013 i am facing the following error on the Sales Order. and form is not loading the data and showing the Error on Page.

i have seen that this error is due to the Ribbon button Code.

```
enter code here
Microsoft Dynamics CRM Error Report Contents
<CrmScriptErrorReport>
  <ReportVersion>1.0</ReportVersion>
  <ScriptErrorDetails>
   <Message>Unable to get property 'ClientVariables' of undefined or null reference</Message>
   <Line>2</Line>
   <URL>/_common/JsProvider.ashx?ids=1959345455-451858892-1713948411-1279630416-1250882489-367493978-19173614-574022791-696891199-2007586035-1552783829&ver=-732227036</URL>
   <PageURL>/_forms/read/page.aspx?etc=1088&id=%7b2D6957CA-A049-E411-93FF-00155D171506%7d&pagemode=iframe&theme=Outlook15White</PageURL>
   <Function>anonymous(){returnthis.get_$L_0().ClientVariables}</Function>
   <CallStack>
    <Function>anonymous(){returnthis.get_$L_0().ClientVariables}</Function>
   </CallStack>
  </ScriptErrorDetails>
  <ClientInformation>
   <BrowserUserAgent>Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/6.0; .NET4.0E; .NET4.0C; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.30729)</BrowserUserAgent>
   <BrowserLanguage>en-US</BrowserLanguage>
   <SystemLanguage>en-US</SystemLanguage>
   <UserLanguage>en-US</UserLanguage>
   <ScreenResolution>1366x768</ScreenResolution>
   <ClientName>Web</ClientName>
   <ClientTime>2014-10-02T17:22:42</ClientTime>
  </ClientInformation>
  <ServerInformation>
    <OrgLanguage>1033</OrgLanguage>
    <OrgCulture>1033</OrgCulture>
    <UserLanguage>1033</UserLanguage>
    <UserCulture>1033</UserCulture>
    <OrgID>{4D4702C4-252C-E411-892F-00155D171505}</OrgID>
    <UserID>{9FDA4ECF-252C-E411-892F-00155D171505}</UserID>
    <CRMVersion>6.0.0.809</CRMVersion>
  </ServerInformation>
</CrmScriptErrorReport>
```

I have did the following:

1- IISRest
2- Reboot system
3- remove the code from SalesOrder_Ribbon webresource when do this then error removed but after reset the IIS again getting the error
4- remove the temporary files from browser
5- use Internet explorer and chrome

Please Help me out this issue.

Regards,
M Salman Malik

Answer (score 1):

When I had this same problem, I fixed it by adding the Read privilege to the Campaign entity.

With that, it started working fine.

Let me know if this works for you too.

Cheers,
Alejandro Cesetti