# CRM2016 Error when I open a Task

Tags: dynamics-crm-2016

When I tried to open a Task in the Activity inside CRM2016 
I have a blank screen. In javascript I have error on

Unable to get property 'ClientVariables' of undefined or null reference

I used the CRM diagnostic tool and I found this error inside the log:

```
2016-03-09 14:34:28.823] Process: w3wp |Organization:5f48a1a7-88df-e511-93f8-00155d50690f |Thread:   20 |Category: Application |User: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |Level: Verbose |ReqId: 7833a3ca-d273-481c-a9fd-1802b2986666 | RetrieveCommand.Execute  ilOffset = 0x2
>Post-Platform Request: Retrieve
[2016-03-09 14:34:28.823] Process: w3wp |Organization:5f48a1a7-88df-e511-93f8-00155d50690f |Thread:   20 |Category: Application |User: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |Level: Info |ReqId: 7833a3ca-d273-481c-a9fd-1802b2986666 | Util.TraceMessage  ilOffset = 0x79
>UserId ({D4940804-3DF9-E211-92B5-00155D05B20C}): FormDescriptor: Creating new form descriptor. LCID: 1033. EntityType: 4212. FormType: Main. FormId: b62ce022-cc0f-4c8c-bb29-21948f70dc74
[2016-03-09 14:34:28.839] Process: w3wp |Organization:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |Thread:   20 |Category: Application |User: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |Level: Error |ReqId: 7833a3ca-d273-481c-a9fd-1802b2986666 | MainApplication.Application_Error  ilOffset = 0x9F
>Request http://d2devcrm10/demotest-2016/_forms/read/layout.aspx?etc=4212&formid=16654191-19ad-48ca-9e46-c4b4fbdad76f&formts=3085142&hash=EA1390550CBFB3F9BE24FC68C3374613C730841943680D5FA152B67E73B4C7B9&isPreview=False&isTurboForm=False&outlook=False failed with exception System.Web.HttpUnhandledException (0x80004005): Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.CellDescriptor..ctor(XmlNode formNode, EntityMetadata entityMetadata, FormDescriptor formDescriptor, TabDescriptor containerTab, Boolean isInFirstColumn, Boolean isInLastColumn)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.CellCollection..ctor(XmlNodeList nodes, EntityMetadata entityMetadata, FormDescriptor formDescriptor, TabDescriptor containerTab)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.RowDescriptor..ctor(IXPathNavigable node, EntityMetadata entityMetadata, FormDescriptor formDescriptor, Boolean rowVisible, TabDescriptor containerTab)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.RowCollection..ctor(XmlNodeList nodes, EntityMetadata entityMetadata, FormDescriptor formDescriptor, Int32 sectionColumns, TabDescriptor containerTab)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.SectionCollection..ctor(XmlNodeList nodes, EntityMetadata entityMetadata, FormDescriptor formDescriptor, TabDescriptor containerTab)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.ColumnDescriptor..ctor(XmlNode columnNode, EntityMetadata entityMetadata, FormDescriptor formDescriptor, TabDescriptor containerTab)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.ColumnCollection..ctor(XmlNodeList nodes, EntityMetadata entityMetadata, FormDescriptor formDescriptor, TabDescriptor containerTab)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.TabDescriptor..ctor(XmlNode formNode, EntityMetadata entityMetadata, FormDescriptor formDescriptor)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.TabCollection..ctor(XmlNode formNode, EntityMetadata entityMetadata, FormDescriptor formDescriptor)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.FormDescriptor.InitializeObjectModel(XmlNode formNode, EntityMetadata entityMetadata, FormType formType)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.FormDescriptor.Initialize(EntityMetadata entityMetadata, XmlNode formXml, Guid formId, FormType formType)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.FormDescriptor..ctor(EntityMetadata entityMetadata, XmlNode formXml, Guid formId, FormType formType, Boolean isUserForm, Boolean isActive, IOrganizationContext context)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.FormDescriptor..ctor(Int32 typeCode, XmlNode formXml, Guid formId, FormType formType, Int64 versionNumber, FormPresentationMode formPresentation, Boolean isActive, IOrganizationContext context)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.Forms.FormDescriptorLoader.LoadCacheData(FormDescriptorCacheKey key, IOrganizationContext context)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Caching.CrmSharedMultiOrgCache`2.LookupEntry(TKey key, IOrganizationContext context)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.Forms.FormDescriptorCache.GetFormDescriptor(Guid formId, IOrganizationContext context)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.Platform.AppFormFilter.<GetFilteredFormList>b__4(Guid formId)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.Controls.AppFormSelector.ConfigureHeader()
   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.Components.UI.CrmUIControlBase.ConfigureControlInternal()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
[2016-03-09 14:34:28.854] Process: w3wp |Organization:5f48a1a7-88df-e511-93f8-00155d50690f |Thread:   20 |Category: Application |User: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |Level: Error |ReqId: 7833a3ca-d273-481c-a9fd-1802b2986666 | ErrorInformation.LogError  ilOffset = 0x17
>MSCRM Error Report:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Error: Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown.

Error Message: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Error Details: Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown.

Source File: Not available

Line Number: Not available

Request URL: http://d2devcrm10/demotest-2016/_forms/read/layout.aspx?etc=4212&formid=16654191-19ad-48ca-9e46-c4b4fbdad76f&formts=3085142&hash=EA1390550CBFB3F9BE24FC68C3374613C730841943680D5FA152B67E73B4C7B9&isPreview=False&isTurboForm=False&outlook=False

Stack Trace Info: [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.CellDescriptor..ctor(XmlNode formNode, EntityMetadata entityMetadata, FormDescriptor formDescriptor, TabDescriptor containerTab, Boolean isInFirstColumn, Boolean isInLastColumn)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.CellCollection..ctor(XmlNodeList nodes, EntityMetadata entityMetadata, FormDescriptor formDescriptor, TabDescriptor containerTab)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.RowDescriptor..ctor(IXPathNavigable node, EntityMetadata entityMetadata, FormDescriptor formDescriptor, Boolean rowVisible, TabDescriptor containerTab)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.RowCollection..ctor(XmlNodeList nodes, EntityMetadata entityMetadata, FormDescriptor formDescriptor, Int32 sectionColumns, TabDescriptor containerTab)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.SectionCollection..ctor(XmlNodeList nodes, EntityMetadata entityMetadata, FormDescriptor formDescriptor, TabDescriptor containerTab)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.ColumnDescriptor..ctor(XmlNode columnNode, EntityMetadata entityMetadata, FormDescriptor formDescriptor, TabDescriptor containerTab)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.ColumnCollection..ctor(XmlNodeList nodes, EntityMetadata entityMetadata, FormDescriptor formDescriptor, TabDescriptor containerTab)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.TabDescriptor..ctor(XmlNode formNode, EntityMetadata entityMetadata, FormDescriptor formDescriptor)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.TabCollection..ctor(XmlNode formNode, EntityMetadata entityMetadata, FormDescriptor formDescriptor)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.FormDescriptor.InitializeObjectModel(XmlNode formNode, EntityMetadata entityMetadata, FormType formType)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.FormDescriptor.Initialize(EntityMetadata entityMetadata, XmlNode formXml, Guid formId, FormType formType)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.FormDescriptor..ctor(EntityMetadata entityMetadata, XmlNode formXml, Guid formId, FormType formType, Boolean isUserForm, Boolean isActive, IOrganizationContext context)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.FormDescriptor..ctor(Int32 typeCode, XmlNode formXml, Guid formId, FormType formType, Int64 versionNumber, FormPresentationMode formPresentation, Boolean isActive, IOrganizationContext context)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.Forms.FormDescriptorLoader.LoadCacheData(FormDescriptorCacheKey key, IOrganizationContext context)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Caching.CrmSharedMultiOrgCache`2.LookupEntry(TKey key, IOrganizationContext context)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.Forms.FormDescriptorCache.GetFormDescriptor(Guid formId, IOrganizationContext context)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.Platform.AppFormFilter.<GetFilteredFormList>b__4(Guid formId)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.Controls.AppFormSelector.ConfigureHeader()
   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.Components.UI.CrmUIControlBase.ConfigureControlInternal()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

[HttpUnhandledException: Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown.]
   at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)


[2016-03-09 14:34:28.854] Process: w3wp |Organization:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |Thread:   20 |Category: Platform |User: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |Level: Info |ReqId: 7833a3ca-d273-481c-a9fd-1802b2986666 | FaultHelper.ConvertToFault  ilOffset = 0x0
>TryConvertToFaultExceptionInternal: exception: System.Web.HttpUnhandledException
[2016-03-09 14:34:28.870] Process: w3wp |Organization:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |Thread:   20 |Category: Platform |User: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |Level: Info |ReqId: 7833a3ca-d273-481c-a9fd-1802b2986666 | ExceptionConverter.DumpExceptionRecursive  ilOffset = 0x294
>NestingDepth: 24
[2016-03-09 14:34:28.870] Process: w3wp |Organization:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |Thread:   20 |Category: Platform |User: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |Level: Info |ReqId: 7833a3ca-d273-481c-a9fd-1802b2986666 | ExceptionConverter.DumpExceptionToTrace  ilOffset = 0x11
>----- dump exception/fault tree (TryConvertToFaultExceptionInternal: before) -----
>>>>>> EXCEPTION: 0
>Type: System.Web.HttpUnhandledException
>Message (65): Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown.
>>>>>> StackTrace (605):
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
><<<<< StackTrace:
>no PluginTrace
>>>>>> EXCEPTION: 1
>Type: System.NullReferenceException
>Message (53): Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>>>>>> StackTrace (4015):
>   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.CellDescriptor..ctor(XmlNode formNode, EntityMetadata entityMetadata, FormDescriptor formDescriptor, TabDescriptor containerTab, Boolean isInFirstColumn, Boolean isInLastColumn)
>   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.CellCollection..ctor(XmlNodeList nodes, EntityMetadata entityMetadata, FormDescriptor formDescriptor, TabDescriptor containerTab)
>   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.RowDescriptor..ctor(IXPathNavigable node, EntityMetadata entityMetadata, FormDescriptor formDescriptor, Boolean rowVisible, TabDescriptor containerTab)
>   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.RowCollection..ctor(XmlNodeList nodes, EntityMetadata entityMetadata, FormDescriptor formDescriptor, Int32 sectionColumns, TabDescriptor containerTab)
>   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.SectionCollection..ctor(XmlNodeList nodes, EntityMetadata entityMetadata, FormDescriptor formDescriptor, TabDescriptor containerTab)
>   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.ColumnDescriptor..ctor(XmlNode columnNode, EntityMetadata entityMetadata, FormDescriptor formDescriptor, TabDescriptor containerTab)
>   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.ColumnCollection..ctor(XmlNodeList nodes, EntityMetadata entityMetadata, FormDescriptor formDescriptor, TabDescriptor containerTab)
>   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.TabDescriptor..ctor(XmlNode formNode, EntityMetadata entityMetadata, FormDescriptor formDescriptor)
>   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.TabCollection..ctor(XmlNode formNode, EntityMetadata entityMetadata, FormDescriptor formDescriptor)
>   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.FormDescriptor.InitializeObjectModel(XmlNode formNode, EntityMetadata entityMetadata, FormType formType)
>   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.FormDescriptor.Initialize(EntityMetadata entityMetadata, XmlNode formXml, Guid formId, FormType formType)
>   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.FormDescriptor..ctor(EntityMetadata entityMetadata, XmlNode formXml, Guid formId, FormType formType, Boolean isUserForm, Boolean isActive, IOrganizationContext context)
>   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.FormDescriptor..ctor(Int32 typeCode, XmlNode formXml, Guid formId, FormType formType, Int64 versionNumber, FormPresentationMode formPresentation, Boolean isActive, IOrganizationContext context)
>   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.Forms.FormDescriptorLoader.LoadCacheData(FormDescriptorCacheKey key, IOrganizationContext context)
>   at Microsoft.Crm.Caching.CrmSharedMultiOrgCache`2.LookupEntry(TKey key, IOrganizationContext context)
>   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.Forms.FormDescriptorCache.GetFormDescriptor(Guid formId, IOrganizationContext context)
>   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.Platform.AppFormFilter.<GetFilteredFormList>b__4(Guid formId)
>   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
>   at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
>   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.Controls.AppFormSelector.ConfigureHeader()
>   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.Components.UI.CrmUIControlBase.ConfigureControlInternal()
>   at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
>   at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
>   at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
>   at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
>   at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
>   at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
>   at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
>   at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
>   at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
>   at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
>   at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
>   at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
>   at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
>   at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
>   at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
><<<<< StackTrace:
>no PluginTrace
>InnerException <null>
><<<<< EXCEPTION: 1
>
[2016-03-09 14:34:28.870] Process: w3wp |Organization:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |Thread:   20 |Category: Platform |User: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |Level: Info |ReqId: 7833a3ca-d273-481c-a9fd-1802b2986666 | ExceptionConverter.ConvertToFault  ilOffset = 0x24
>NestingDepth: 24
[2016-03-09 14:34:28.870] Process: w3wp |Organization:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |Thread:   20 |Category: Platform |User: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |Level: Info |ReqId: 7833a3ca-d273-481c-a9fd-1802b2986666 | ExceptionConverter.ConvertToFault  ilOffset = 0x57
>ToSingleFaultUntyped: enter
[2016-03-09 14:34:28.870] Process: w3wp |Organization:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |Thread:   20 |Category: Platform |User: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |Level: Info |ReqId: 7833a3ca-d273-481c-a9fd-1802b2986666 | ExceptionConverter.ToSingleFaultUnTyped  ilOffset = 0x35
>ToSingleFault/FE<OSF>: enter
[2016-03-09 14:34:28.870] Process: w3wp |Organization:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |Thread:   20 |Category: Platform |User: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |Level: Info |ReqId: 7833a3ca-d273-481c-a9fd-1802b2986666 | ExceptionConverter.ToSingleFaultUnTyped  ilOffset = 0x3A
>ToSingleFaultOther: enter
[2016-03-09 14:34:28.870] Process: w3wp |Organization:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |Thread:   20 |Category: Platform |User: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |Level: Info |ReqId: 7833a3ca-d273-481c-a9fd-1802b2986666 | ExceptionConverter.ConvertMessageAndErrorCode  ilOffset = 0x21
>enter: ConvertMessageAndErrorCode: System.Web.HttpUnhandledException
[2016-03-09 14:34:28.870] Process: w3wp |Organization:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |Thread:   20 |Category: Platform |User: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |Level: Error |ReqId: 7833a3ca-d273-481c-a9fd-1802b2986666 | ExceptionConverter.ConvertMessageAndErrorCode  ilOffset = 0x221
>System.Web.HttpUnhandledException: Microsoft Dynamics CRM has experienced an error. Reference number for administrators or support: #485A06D2: System.Web.HttpUnhandledException (0x80004005): Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.CellDescriptor..ctor(XmlNode formNode, EntityMetadata entityMetadata, FormDescriptor formDescriptor, TabDescriptor containerTab, Boolean isInFirstColumn, Boolean isInLastColumn)
>   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.CellCollection..ctor(XmlNodeList nodes, EntityMetadata entityMetadata, FormDescriptor formDescriptor, TabDescriptor containerTab)
>   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.RowDescriptor..ctor(IXPathNavigable node, EntityMetadata entityMetadata, FormDescriptor formDescriptor, Boolean rowVisible, TabDescriptor containerTab)
>   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.RowCollection..ctor(XmlNodeList nodes, EntityMetadata entityMetadata, FormDescriptor formDescriptor, Int32 sectionColumns, TabDescriptor containerTab)
>   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.SectionCollection..ctor(XmlNodeList nodes, EntityMetadata entityMetadata, FormDescriptor formDescriptor, TabDescriptor containerTab)
>   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.ColumnDescriptor..ctor(XmlNode columnNode, EntityMetadata entityMetadata, FormDescriptor formDescriptor, TabDescriptor containerTab)
>   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.ColumnCollection..ctor(XmlNodeList nodes, EntityMetadata entityMetadata, FormDescriptor formDescriptor, TabDescriptor containerTab)
>   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.TabDescriptor..ctor(XmlNode formNode, EntityMetadata entityMetadata, FormDescriptor formDescriptor)
>   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.TabCollection..ctor(XmlNode formNode, EntityMetadata entityMetadata, FormDescriptor formDescriptor)
>   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.FormDescriptor.InitializeObjectModel(XmlNode formNode, EntityMetadata entityMetadata, FormType formType)
>   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.FormDescriptor.Initialize(EntityMetadata entityMetadata, XmlNode formXml, Guid formId, FormType formType)
>   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.FormDescriptor..ctor(EntityMetadata entityMetadata, XmlNode formXml, Guid formId, FormType formType, Boolean isUserForm, Boolean isActive, IOrganizationContext context)
>   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.FormDescriptor..ctor(Int32 typeCode, XmlNode formXml, Guid formId, FormType formType, Int64 versionNumber, FormPresentationMode formPresentation, Boolean isActive, IOrganizationContext context)
>   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.Forms.FormDescriptorLoader.LoadCacheData(FormDescriptorCacheKey key, IOrganizationContext context)
>   at Microsoft.Crm.Caching.CrmSharedMultiOrgCache`2.LookupEntry(TKey key, IOrganizationContext context)
>   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.Forms.FormDescriptorCache.GetFormDescriptor(Guid formId, IOrganizationContext context)
>   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.Platform.AppFormFilter.<GetFilteredFormList>b__4(Guid formId)
>   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
>   at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
>   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.Controls.AppFormSelector.ConfigureHeader()
>   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.Components.UI.CrmUIControlBase.ConfigureControlInternal()
>   at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
>   at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
>   at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
>   at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
>   at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
>   at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
>   at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
>   at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
>   at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
>   at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
>   at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
>   at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
>   at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
>   at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
>   at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
[2016-03-09 14:34:28.870] Process: w3wp |Organization:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |Thread:   20 |Category: Platform |User: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |Level: Info |ReqId: 7833a3ca-d273-481c-a9fd-1802b2986666 | ExceptionConverter.ConvertMessageAndErrorCode  ilOffset = 0x281
>exit: ConvertMessageAndErrorCode: errorCode: 0x80040216; message: System.Web.HttpUnhandledException: Microsoft Dynamics CRM has experienced an error. Reference number for administrators or support: #485A06D2
[2016-03-09 14:34:28.886] Process: w3wp |Organization:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |Thread:   20 |Category: Platform |User: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |Level: Info |ReqId: 7833a3ca-d273-481c-a9fd-1802b2986666 | ExceptionConverter.ToSingleFaultOther  ilOffset = 0x2F
>ToSingleFaultCommon: enter
[2016-03-09 14:34:28.886] Process: w3wp |Organization:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |Thread:   20 |Category: Platform |User: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |Level: Info |ReqId: 7833a3ca-d273-481c-a9fd-1802b2986666 | ExceptionConverter.ToSingleFaultOther  ilOffset = 0x2F
>no PluginTrace
[2016-03-09 14:34:28.886] Process: w3wp |Organization:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |Thread:   20 |Category: Platform |User: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |Level: Info |ReqId: 7833a3ca-d273-481c-a9fd-1802b2986666 | ExceptionConverter.ToSingleFaultOther  ilOffset = 0x2F
>no CrmExceptionFaults
[2016-03-09 14:34:28.886] Process: w3wp |Organization:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |Thread:   20 |Category: Platform |User: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |Level: Info |ReqId: 7833a3ca-d273-481c-a9fd-1802b2986666 | ExceptionConverter.ToSingleFaultCommon  ilOffset = 0x183
>IncludeCallStack: True
[2016-03-09 14:34:28.886] Process: w3wp |Organization:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |Thread:   20 |Category: Platform |User: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |Level: Info |ReqId: 7833a3ca-d273-481c-a9fd-1802b2986666 | ExceptionConverter.ConvertToFault  ilOffset = 0x24
>NestingDepth: 24
[2016-03-09 14:34:28.886] Process: w3wp |Organization:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |Thread:   20 |Category: Platform |User: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |Level: Info |ReqId: 7833a3ca-d273-481c-a9fd-1802b2986666 | ExceptionConverter.ConvertToFault  ilOffset = 0x69
>ToSingleFaultUntyped: enter
[2016-03-09 14:34:28.886] Process: w3wp |Organization:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |Thread:   20 |Category: Platform |User: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |Level: Info |ReqId: 7833a3ca-d273-481c-a9fd-1802b2986666 | ExceptionConverter.ToSingleFaultUnTyped  ilOffset = 0x35
>ToSingleFault/FE<OSF>: enter
[2016-03-09 14:34:28.886] Process: w3wp |Organization:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |Thread:   20 |Category: Platform |User: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |Level: Info |ReqId: 7833a3ca-d273-481c-a9fd-1802b2986666 | ExceptionConverter.ToSingleFaultUnTyped  ilOffset = 0x3A
>ToSingleFaultOther: enter
[2016-03-09 14:34:28.886] Process: w3wp |Organization:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |Thread:   20 |Category: Platform |User: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |Level: Info |ReqId: 7833a3ca-d273-481c-a9fd-1802b2986666 | ExceptionConverter.ConvertMessageAndErrorCode  ilOffset = 0x21
>enter: ConvertMessageAndErrorCode: System.NullReferenceException
```

Comment: Do you have any js active on the form you're trying to open? It sounds as if you're having code that is looking for a field that isn't present on the form.

Comment: Hi Richard, no.. I cheked but I don't have any js active in the form. This is the problem... because all js are disabled....

Comment: If all js is disabled no code is causing an error so it sounds unlikely. Since you are just opening a record it isn't a plugin causing the issue.

Comment: A couple of other people have suggested they resolved this by looking at security roles - particularly around the Campaign entity: https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/146641 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26162531/unable-to-get-property-clientvariables-of-undefined-or-null-reference-in-crm-2